# grub-install : File descriptor 3 leaked on vgs invocation

Tags: grub2, lvm, software-raid

I installed Debian Jessie on a LVM in a software RAID 1.

To make sure MBR are written on both disks of the RAID 1, I run `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` (as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25513)) and select both disks.

I get those errors :

```
root@bouzin:/home/jerome# dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
Installing for i386-pc platform.
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[1038681]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 4760: grub-install
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[1038681]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 4760: grub-install
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[1038681]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 4760: grub-install
Installation finished. No error reported.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[1038681]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 4789: grub-install
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[1038681]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 4789: grub-install
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[1038681]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 4789: grub-install
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
done
```

Is this something to be worried about ?

[This bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=549976) suggests such warnings may appear and are harmless, but those should have been fixed already AFAIU.

More details on my install, in case it would be relevant :

I use 2 hard drives. On each drive is a single whole-drive partition used for the RAID. I create one RAID1 with both partitions. I create a LVM on the RAID and create 3 logical volumes in the LVM for swap, / and /home.

During installation, I only wrote the MBR on one drive, either by mistake or because the installer wouldn't allow me to write it on both. I want to be able to boot with only one drive, so I need the MBR written on both drives.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The warning messages about the file descriptor leaking are indeed harmless, and are being tracked in [bug 592834](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=592834). You might want to contribute your findings there; I'm not sure Colin (the maintainer) has been able to reproduce the bug in this instance...

Comment: Thanks, I added my issue to the bug report you indicated.

Comment: I found this issue on Debian 9 Stretch as well. My partition scheme is based on lvm. And I had renamed some Volume Group and Logical Vulumes recently.