# grub not working with lvm

Tags: boot, grub2, lvm, grub, uefi

I have a dualbooted system with windows + ubuntu on LVM:

```
/dev/sda1 -> efi
/dev/sda2-4 -> windows
/dev/sda5 -> LVM

/dev/vgsys/root -> /
/dev/vgsys/home -> /home
```

The drive it was on started getting corrupted so I recently transferred to a new SSD. Upon transferring and reinstalling some programs that had been corrupted (like wpasupplicant and sed, LOL) the system was working fine until, like a moron, I performed a system upgrade and rebooting despite seeing grub spit out some errors I've never seen before. Now my system doesn't boot and I'm trying to figure out why via a system rescue boot drive.

I tried purging and reinstalling grub which did appear to address some issues I was having (at the expense of losing some custom grub config settings that i did not back up, of course) but whenever I run `grub-install` or `update-grub` I get these bizarre and terrifying errors I haven't been able to find documented anywhere online. I copied them by hand so it might not be 100% accurate:

```
File descriptor 4 (/dev/sda1) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 12201: grub-install
Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared to allow empty values.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as array.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as array.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as array.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as integer.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as array.
  Ignoring invalid activation/mlock_filter entry in config file
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as integer.
  Ignoring too small pv_min_size 0KB, using default 512KB.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as boolean.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared to allow empty values.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as integer.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as string.
  Internal error:  cfg tree element not declared as array.
  Expecting string in devices/types in config file
  _control_fd: close failed: Bad file descriptor
```

then it seems to repeat another time.

I actually have seen `File descriptor 4 (/dev/sda1) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 12201: grub-install` before and it is [allegedly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212958/grub-install-file-descriptor-3-leaked-on-vgs-invocation) harmless. Some of other errors seem to also be related to LVM like `pv_min_size` so I'm sort of guessing this is an LVM issue in general.

I tried to do a `grub-install` on an external thumbdrive that I created with an efi and boot partition:

```
umount /boot/efi
mv /boot /boot.bad
mkdir /boot
mount /dev/sdb2 /boot
mkdir /boot/efi
mount /dev/sdb1 /boot/efi
grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi
```

and actually didn't get any errors. But whenever I run `update-grub` I get those errors again. Where are they coming from and how do I fix it?

update: I found [this page](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/13a404161a49942dc84abfa8a78b0d59db5d0c5b6a7ba8b7381567578697d4d9?environmentId=300) that contains some of the `cfg tree element..` messages, wonder what it means...

Comment: Does running `lvs` or similar also give these errors?

Comment: hm it looks like it does! didn't realize since i was using lvs outside of the chroot, which doesn't yield the same errors.

Comment: Wait, so if you run `lvs` from other boot media it doesn't complain but running the copy in the system does?  Sounds like maybe your lvm binaries are corrupt.

Comment: yes!! thank you!!! I had the same thought and now `update-grub` is not giving me issues! i'll do some more testing in a couple hours but fingers crossed i can mark this as resolved (if you do the 'answer question' i'd be happy to mark it as the solution). there's a lot more corrupt than i thought though it's probably a good idea to do a fresh install soon.

Answer (score 1):

as @psusi pointed out, the issue was that my lvm binaries were corrupt. I ran

```
apt-cache depends lvm2 | grep Depends | awk '{print $2}' | xargs apt install --reinstall -y
apt install --reinstall -y lvm2
```

to reinstall lvm2 and all its dependencies, which solved my problem.